# To be only verb to deviate in second person singular?

Tags: verbs

"To be" is irregular in its second form singular, i.e. 'you are'.

Is "to be" the only case where the second form singular deviates?

In other verbs I think of, the baseform (infinitive form, first person singular) seems to be repeated for:

- 1st person singular
- 2nd person singular
- All plural forms

The same question applied for the past tense.

Reason is again I am not sure if I should foresee all 6 forms in the database, as this will turn into a lot of redundant data.
If "to be" is the only verb that that deviates, I can write something custom for this verb but I wouldn't have to store all 6 forms.

Comment: Yes, _be_ is a very strange verb indeed. By far the most irregular in English, it is virtually always an auxiliary verb, usually contracted. Though it does have a regular present participle (_-ing_ form), which modal auxiliaries don't.

Comment: @JohnLawler So this means I can assume that other verbs have the same form for the other person forms (1s, 2s, 1p, 2p, 3p)?

Comment: That's correct. Person and number are only marked on _be_ and in the 3rd Singular Present. And that's going out of use; [English inflection](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) is pretty much in the Intensive Care ward.

Comment: Yes. Note that that’s true for both the present and past tense forms where *be* is the only verb to inflect at all!